# How to require ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to test my RESTful resource in Rails:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'activeresource'

class Event < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3000"
end

events = Event.find(:all)
puts events.map(&:name)
```

I have installed gem:

> gem install activeresource

But when I launch my code I get the error message:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- activeresource (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from service.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

How can I require ActiveResource?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a typo in your require, the following is the correct one:

```
require 'active_resource'
```

Answer (score 3):

With bunder you can do this just with

```
gem "activeresource", require: "active_resource"
```

Normally gems requires file with name equal to gem’s name, with `gem "foo" :require => bar` syntax you can specify different file to be included by default.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do it this way:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'activeresource'
require 'active_resource'
```

You can also specify which version of activeresource you want by

```
gem 'activeresource', '=3.0.7'
```

for example. Or you can omit this line completely, but this way it's cleaner... and it makes sure that you get the right version.

Hope this helps, NoICE